# Create terraform variable containing single quote

Tags: terraform

I need to configure a folder name containing 2 single quotes inside :

```
/team/a/company/incoming/test/${date('yyyyMMdd')}
```

While escaping the `$` was easy, I can't find a solution to escape single quotes.

I tried to create a local variable in different ways :

**1.** using backslash `\` to escape :

```
locals {
    upload_folder = "/team/a/company/incoming/test/$${date(\'yyyyMMdd\')}"
}
```

I got an error executing `terraform validate` : `The symbol "'" is not a valid escape sequence selector.`

**2.** using double backslash `\\` to escape :

```
locals {
    upload_folder = "/team/a/company/incoming/test/$${date(\\'yyyyMMdd\\')}"
}
```

Valid for terraform but result was not what I expected  :

```
/team/a/company/incoming/test/${date(\'yyyyMMdd\')}
```

**3.** doubling single quote `''` to escape :

```
locals {
    upload_folder = "/team/a/company/incoming/test/$${date(''yyyyMMdd'')}"
}
```

Also valid for terraform but result was not what I expected  :

```
/team/a/company/incoming/test/${date(''yyyyMMdd'')}
```

What's the simpliest solution to escape single quote in variable name ?

Comment: am I missing something whats wrong with just `upload_folder = "/team/a/company/incoming/test/$${date('yyyyMMdd')}"` when i use this and output the value i get `foo = "/team/a/company/incoming/test/${date('yyyyMMdd')}"`

Comment: it might also be worth while listing out what you expect or want the result to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'` character is not special in the Terraform language, so it should not be necessary to escape it at all:

```
locals {
  upload_folder = "/team/a/company/incoming/test/$${date('yyyyMMdd')}"
}
```

The `$${` escape sequence for `${` is the crucial part, because otherwise Terraform will think that you intend `date('yyyyMMdd')` to be Terraform function call expression, and so Terraform will reject it due to single quotes not being allowed in the Terraform language.

However, once you've escaped `${` Terraform will just see this entire sequence as a single literal string (aside from replacing `$${` with just `${`) and so those `'` characters are just another part of that string, not interpreted in any special way by Terraform at all.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think I lost myself attempting to have the wanted result. It works indeed.